# XAML source file compilation in VS 2008

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2008

I have a C# project in a VS 2008 solution, which includes a lot of .xaml (for WPF) and other independent .cs source files. Is there any possibility to compile a single .xaml file, without having to build / rebuild the entire project in VS2008, because that would take a lot of unnecessary time? The context menu on the .xaml file (right click) and the "Build" menu don't seem to have this option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to exclude those xaml files from your project (right click on the file on solution explorer). (and if you don't use MVVM) comment line from .cs files  where you are using decalartion from xaml files. When you need the xaml load the back.

Comment: I need to compile a single xaml inside a project. Why would I exclude the file?

Comment: exclude the files that you don't want to compile